# Rspec send emails even when shouldn't - implement deliver_later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got a mailer job when after 2, 10 and 26 days email should get send. After any other number of days for example 6 there should be no email. Locally it works but `rspec` failed test below

```
RSpec.describe RemindUnconfirmedUsersWithoutBanker do
  subject(:remind_unconfirmed_users) { described_class.call(number_of_days) }

  let(:number_of_days) { [2, 10, 26] }

  before do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
    allow(InvitationMailer).to receive_message_chain(:confirmation_instructions, :deliver)
  end

  context "when created_at equals to 6 days" do
    it "does not invite user again" do
      create_list(:user, 2, created_at: 6.days.ago, confirmed_at: nil)
      remind_unconfirmed_users
      expect(InvitationMailer).not_to have_received(:confirmation_instructions)
    end
  end
end
```

with error

> 1.1) Failure/Error: expect(InvitationMailer).not_to have_received(:confirmation_instructions)
>
> ```
>    (InvitationMailer (class)).confirmation_instructions(no args)
>         expected: 0 times with any arguments
>         received: 1 time
>   # ./spec/services/remind_unconfirmed_users_without_banker_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```
>
> 1.2) Failure/Error: expect(InvitationMailer).not_to have_received(:confirmation_instructions)
>
> ```
>   (InvitationMailer (class)).confirmation_instructions(*(any args))
>         expected: 0 times with any arguments
>         received: 2 times with any arguments
>   # >./spec/services/remind_unconfirmed_users_without_banker_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

**Edit**

I think I have to implement somehow `deliver_later` because my service has this method

**remind_unconfirmed_users_without_banker.rb**

```
  def resend_invitation(users_to_mail)
    users_to_mail.each do |user|
      Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(user, user.confirmation_token).deliver_later
    end
  end
```

**Edit2**

If I delete `confirmed_at: nil` and leave `create_list(:user, 2, created_at: 6.days.ago)` test will pass. Empty field and `nil` will not be the same in this case?